# Are PyArg_ParseTuple() "s" format specifiers useful in Python 3.x C API?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to write a Python C extension that processes byte strings, and I have something basically working for Python 2.x and Python 3.x.

For the Python 2.x code, near the start of my function, I currently have a line:

```
    if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "s#:in_bytes", &src_ptr, &src_len))
    ...
```

I notice that the `s#` format specifier accepts both Unicode strings and byte strings. I really just want it to accept byte strings and reject Unicode. For Python 2.x, this might be "good enough"--the standard `hashlib` seems to do the same, accepting Unicode as well as byte strings. However, Python 3.x is meant to clean up the Unicode/byte string mess and not let the two be interchangeable.

So, I'm surprised to find that [in Python 3.x, the `s` format specifiers](http://docs.python.org/3.1/c-api/arg.html) for `PyArg_ParseTuple()` still seem to accept Unicode and provide a "default encoded string version" of the Unicode. This seems to go against the principles of Python 3.x, making the `s` format specifiers unusable in practice. Is my analysis correct, or am I missing something?

Looking at the implementation for `hashlib` for Python 3.x (e.g. see [`md5module.c`](http://svn.python.org/view/python/branches/release31-maint/Modules/md5module.c?view=markup), function `MD5_update()` and its use of [`GET_BUFFER_VIEW_OR_ERROUT()`](http://svn.python.org/view/python/branches/release31-maint/Modules/hashlib.h?view=markup) macro) I see that it avoids the `s` format specifiers, and just takes a generic object (`O` specifier) and then does various explicit type checks using the [`GET_BUFFER_VIEW_OR_ERROUT()`](http://svn.python.org/view/python/branches/release31-maint/Modules/hashlib.h?view=markup) macro. Is this what we have to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with you -- it's one of several spots where the C API migration of Python 3 was clearly not designed as carefully and thouroughly as the Python coder-visible parts.  I do also agree that probably the best workaround for now is focusing on "buffer views", per that macro -- until and unless something better gets designed into a future Python C API (don't hold your breath waiting for that to happen, though;-).